Laptop Wifi not working for several days
Laptop (Ubuntu Mate, 22.04) Wifi not working - seems like it works for like 10 seconds after logging in, then it drops and is totally unavailable (greyed in the menu).
Then accessing the internet is only possible using ethernet or USB tethering.
During past days i tried so many options founds on forums:

changing Network Manager configuration
changing Netplan conf
changing power management in /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
reverting to previous kernel versions
changing UEFI wireless settings and power settings
all the software is up to date (also sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware was done)
tried to fix from live session
rfkill list writes there is no soft block nor hard block

Nothing solved the problem.
During the live session the wifi worked normally. This is unfortunately not true anymore => no wifi even in live session now
Strange that during those days this problem also occured on my son’s laptop (also Ubuntu Mate 22.04) and my wife’s one („standard“ Ubuntu 22.04)
It is not caused by our home wifi as 1) our android devices has no problem connecting to it 2) the laptops have the problem on other wifis also
EDIT: the laptop is dual booting Windows 10, on Windows the wifi work normally

Output of lspci -nnk -d ::0280
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:9df0] (rev 30)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:4234]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi


Output of sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi right after reboot - when the wifi is on for short period of time
[    7.905173] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    7.912744] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected crf-id 0x2816, cnv-id 0x1000100 wfpm id 0x80000000
[    7.912757] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: PCI dev 9df0/4234, rev=0x312, rfid=0x105110
[    7.964098] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 0
[    7.964104] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 1
[    7.964107] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 2
[    7.964109] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 3
[    7.964111] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 4
[    7.964114] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 6
[    7.964116] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 8
[    7.964118] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 9
[    7.964120] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 10
[    7.964122] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 11
[    7.964125] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 15
[    7.964127] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 16
[    7.964129] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 18
[    7.964131] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 19
[    7.964134] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 20
[    7.964136] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 21
[    7.964139] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 28
[    7.968030] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.fae53a8b.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    8.215682] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560, REV=0x312
[    8.287147] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 58:a0:23:ef:cb:e4, OTP minor version: 0x4
[    9.549761] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[    9.855287] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Registered PHC clock: iwlwifi-PTP, with index: 0
[   45.039407] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: time out after 2000ms.
[   45.039426] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Current CMD queue read_ptr 214 write_ptr 215
[   45.061441] WARNING: CPU: 6 PID: 3263 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/trans.c:2237 __iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x1a0/0x1b0 [iwlwifi]
[   45.061713]  intel_rapl_msr nfnetlink kvm snd_hda_core snd_hwdep irqbypass snd_pcm iwlmvm dell_laptop uvcvideo nls_iso8859_1 rapl snd_seq_midi dell_smm_hwmon intel_cstate joydev videobuf2_vmalloc snd_seq_midi_event mac80211 btusb uvc btrtl videobuf2_memops snd_rawmidi btintel videobuf2_v4l2 snd_seq libarc4 btbcm videodev input_leds videobuf2_common btmtk typec_displayport serio_raw mc snd_seq_device cmdlinepart bluetooth dell_wmi iwlwifi snd_timer spi_nor dell_smbios processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy dell_wmi_sysman processor_thermal_device dcdbas ecdh_generic ecc hid_sensor_gyro_3d hid_sensor_incl_3d hid_sensor_custom_intel_hinge hid_sensor_magn_3d hid_sensor_accel_3d hid_sensor_rotation processor_thermal_wt_hint processor_thermal_rfim firmware_attributes_class ledtrig_audio dell_wmi_descriptor wmi_bmof hid_multitouch mei_me mtd snd hid_sensor_trigger processor_thermal_rapl industrialio_triggered_buffer cfg80211 soundcore intel_rapl_common kfifo_buf processor_thermal_wt_req mei hid_sensor_iio_common industrialio
[   45.062036] RIP: 0010:__iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x1a0/0x1b0 [iwlwifi]
[   45.062209]  ? __iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x1a0/0x1b0 [iwlwifi]
[   45.062333]  ? __iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x1a0/0x1b0 [iwlwifi]
[   45.062463]  iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x1a/0x50 [iwlwifi]
[   45.062574]  iwl_force_nmi+0x60/0x100 [iwlwifi]
[   45.062685]  iwl_trans_sync_nmi_with_addr+0x151/0x170 [iwlwifi]
[   45.062762]  iwl_trans_pcie_sync_nmi+0x6a/0x80 [iwlwifi]
[   45.062863]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd_sync+0x356/0x370 [iwlwifi]
[   45.062965]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd+0xb8/0x170 [iwlwifi]
[   45.063082]  iwl_trans_send_cmd+0x74/0xf0 [iwlwifi]
[   45.065160] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[   45.065170] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi device config registers:
[   45.065310] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000000: 9df08086 00100406 02800030 00800010 a121c004 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   45.065320] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 42348086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 000001ff
[   45.065329] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000040: 00928010 10000ec0 00100c10 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   45.065351] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000060: 00000000 00080812 00000405 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   45.065359] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000080: 000f0011 00002000 00003000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   45.065366] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 000000a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   45.065374] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 000000c0: 00000000 00000000 c823d001 0d000008 00814005 fee004f8 00000000 00000000
[   45.065381] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 000000e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   45.065388] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000100: 14c00000 ff000000 000000ff 00462031 00000000 00002000 00000000 00000000
[   45.065396] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000120: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   45.065403] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000140: 00000000 00000000 00000000 16410018 00000000 0001001e 00481e1f 00000000
[   45.065409] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
[   45.065436] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000000: 00c89002 00000040 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   45.065444] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000020: 00000000 0c04000c 00000312 d55555d5 d55555d5 d55555d5 80008040 041f0042
[   45.289568] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Hardware error detected.  Restarting.
[   45.312218] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: HW error, resetting before reading
[   45.318571] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   45.318577] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x00000042, valid: 447487637
[   45.318581] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 46.fae53a8b.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
[   45.318584] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0F6D9B46 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[   45.318587] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFDD53131 | trm_hw_status0
[   45.318590] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x937FFB7E | trm_hw_status1
[   45.318592] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xEAE029AB | branchlink2
[   45.318594] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x521AEFB3 | interruptlink1
[   45.318597] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2EBC12E5 | interruptlink2
[   45.318599] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x3F732FFA | data1
[   45.318601] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x661514DC | data2
[   45.318603] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x37CD3E99 | data3
[   45.318605] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF470D5D7 | beacon time
[   45.318607] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xBBDB7162 | tsf low
[   45.318609] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4AA902D8 | tsf hi
[   45.318611] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7AD5328B | time gp1
[   45.318613] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6B973158 | time gp2
[   45.318615] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4E2507DF | uCode revision type
[   45.318618] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4E782749 | uCode version major
[   45.318620] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4A9EBDFC | uCode version minor
[   45.318622] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDDD9E3DE | hw version
[   45.318624] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDDFA82EC | board version
[   45.318626] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x72BF9AA1 | hcmd
[   45.318628] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC15BB77F | isr0
[   45.318630] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xCCD41DB2 | isr1
[   45.318632] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFF8DECFE | isr2
[   45.318634] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB1ADD70F | isr3
[   45.318636] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x88DABAFB | isr4
[   45.318638] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC51C574C | last cmd Id
[   45.318641] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x99CBB75A | wait_event
[   45.318643] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6678A4FF | l2p_control
[   45.318645] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA16BFFD4 | l2p_duration
[   45.318647] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x9E60BA41 | l2p_mhvalid
[   45.318649] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x58FFF2F3 | l2p_addr_match
[   45.318651] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7F5FAF3B | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   45.318653] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x58B02A6F | timestamp
[   45.318656] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE501F3D7 | flow_handler
[   45.318694] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   45.318696] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x00000042, valid: 393320040
[   45.318698] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA4DD139F | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   45.318701] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDF7B7207 | umac branchlink1
[   45.318703] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8F4B1E70 | umac branchlink2
[   45.318705] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6D6A5CD5 | umac interruptlink1
[   45.318708] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x9E552BCB | umac interruptlink2
[   45.318710] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB8D6AEDB | umac data1
[   45.318712] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0638D973 | umac data2
[   45.318714] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x55C96A35 | umac data3
[   45.318716] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFDFB63FD | umac major
[   45.318718] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x9EF4D556 | umac minor
[   45.318720] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDABF7843 | frame pointer
[   45.318722] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB425FE89 | stack pointer
[   45.318725] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFCDFEF9D | last host cmd
[   45.318727] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xCE9B83E7 | isr status reg
[   45.318749] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
[   45.318751] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | IML/ROM error/state
[   45.318772] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | IML/ROM data1
[   45.318790] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   45.318833] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   45.318908] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   45.318994] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   45.319071] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   45.319147] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   45.319226] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   45.319303] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   45.319380] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   45.319458] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   45.319536] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   45.319618] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   45.319697] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   45.319775] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_PREV_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   45.319853] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_WIFI_FSEQ_VERSION
[   45.319930] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_BT_FSEQ_VERSION
[   45.320015] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_CLASS_TP_VERSION
[   45.320033] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
[   45.320210] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Failed to dump region: id=1, type=10
[   47.427659] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Failed to dump region: id=21, type=10
[   47.454728] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 8 [0xa5a5a5a2]
[   49.515919] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x0, CPU2 Status: 0x0
[   49.515962] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_ARC1_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x2f
[   49.515986] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: HPM_SECONDARY_DEVICE_STATE: 0x42
[   49.516008] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_MAC_OTP_CFG7_ADDR: 0x0
[   49.516030] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_MAC_OTP_CFG7_DATA: 0x4
[   49.516051] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC PC: 0xc0080000
[   49.516073] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC PC: 0x60920
[   49.516079] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   49.766106] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
[   49.766140] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   49.766150] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 2122219134
[   49.766156] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 46.fae53a8b.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
[   49.766160] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[   49.766165] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | trm_hw_status0
[   49.766169] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | trm_hw_status1
[   49.766172] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | branchlink2
[   49.766175] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | interruptlink1
[   49.766178] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | interruptlink2
[   49.766181] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | data1
[   49.766184] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | data2
[   49.766187] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | data3
[   49.766190] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | beacon time
[   49.766193] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | tsf low
[   49.766196] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | tsf hi
[   49.766199] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | time gp1
[   49.766202] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | time gp2
[   49.766205] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | uCode revision type
[   49.766209] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | uCode version major
[   49.766212] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | uCode version minor
[   49.766215] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | hw version
[   49.766218] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | board version
[   49.766221] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | hcmd
[   49.766224] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | isr0
[   49.766227] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | isr1
[   49.766230] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | isr2
[   49.766233] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | isr3
[   49.766236] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | isr4
[   49.766238] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | last cmd Id
[   49.766242] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | wait_event
[   49.766245] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | l2p_control
[   49.766248] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | l2p_duration
[   49.766251] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | l2p_mhvalid
[   49.766254] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | l2p_addr_match
[   49.766257] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   49.766260] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | timestamp
[   49.766263] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7E7E7E7E | flow_handler
[   49.766300] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   49.766304] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   49.766307] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink2
[   49.766310] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
[   49.766313] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[   49.766316] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac data1
[   49.766319] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac data2
[   49.766322] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[   49.766325] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac major
[   49.766328] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac minor
[   49.766331] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | frame pointer
[   49.766334] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | stack pointer
[   49.766337] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[   49.766340] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[   49.766361] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
[   49.766364] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | IML/ROM error/state
[   49.766384] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | IML/ROM data1
[   49.766401] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   49.766426] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xEB332FE6 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   49.766440] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   49.766451] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD6F7BDE0 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   49.766463] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   49.766475] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xEA29E6D1 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   49.766486] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF47C2484 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   49.766498] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB87FCB7B | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   49.766509] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0D8A0253 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   49.766520] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   49.766534] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   49.766549] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   49.766594] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   49.766614] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE381E3CF | FSEQ_PREV_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   49.766626] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA43B1169 | FSEQ_WIFI_FSEQ_VERSION
[   49.766638] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8C528C67 | FSEQ_BT_FSEQ_VERSION
[   49.766649] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6DF9F835 | FSEQ_CLASS_TP_VERSION
[   49.766663] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[   49.766671] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   49.766677] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[   49.766685] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   50.562644] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: mac start retry 0
[   50.563014]  intel_rapl_msr nfnetlink kvm snd_hda_core snd_hwdep irqbypass snd_pcm iwlmvm dell_laptop uvcvideo nls_iso8859_1 rapl snd_seq_midi dell_smm_hwmon intel_cstate joydev videobuf2_vmalloc snd_seq_midi_event mac80211 btusb uvc btrtl videobuf2_memops snd_rawmidi btintel videobuf2_v4l2 snd_seq libarc4 btbcm videodev input_leds videobuf2_common btmtk typec_displayport serio_raw mc snd_seq_device cmdlinepart bluetooth dell_wmi iwlwifi snd_timer spi_nor dell_smbios processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy dell_wmi_sysman processor_thermal_device dcdbas ecdh_generic ecc hid_sensor_gyro_3d hid_sensor_incl_3d hid_sensor_custom_intel_hinge hid_sensor_magn_3d hid_sensor_accel_3d hid_sensor_rotation processor_thermal_wt_hint processor_thermal_rfim firmware_attributes_class ledtrig_audio dell_wmi_descriptor wmi_bmof hid_multitouch mei_me mtd snd hid_sensor_trigger processor_thermal_rapl industrialio_triggered_buffer cfg80211 soundcore intel_rapl_common kfifo_buf processor_thermal_wt_req mei hid_sensor_iio_common industrialio
[   50.579623] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to synchronize multicast groups update
[   50.580065]  intel_rapl_msr nfnetlink kvm snd_hda_core snd_hwdep irqbypass snd_pcm iwlmvm dell_laptop uvcvideo nls_iso8859_1 rapl snd_seq_midi dell_smm_hwmon intel_cstate joydev videobuf2_vmalloc snd_seq_midi_event mac80211 btusb uvc btrtl videobuf2_memops snd_rawmidi btintel videobuf2_v4l2 snd_seq libarc4 btbcm videodev input_leds videobuf2_common btmtk typec_displayport serio_raw mc snd_seq_device cmdlinepart bluetooth dell_wmi iwlwifi snd_timer spi_nor dell_smbios processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy dell_wmi_sysman processor_thermal_device dcdbas ecdh_generic ecc hid_sensor_gyro_3d hid_sensor_incl_3d hid_sensor_custom_intel_hinge hid_sensor_magn_3d hid_sensor_accel_3d hid_sensor_rotation processor_thermal_wt_hint processor_thermal_rfim firmware_attributes_class ledtrig_audio dell_wmi_descriptor wmi_bmof hid_multitouch mei_me mtd snd hid_sensor_trigger processor_thermal_rapl industrialio_triggered_buffer cfg80211 soundcore intel_rapl_common kfifo_buf processor_thermal_wt_req mei hid_sensor_iio_common industrialio
[   50.583253]  ? __iwl_err+0x18a/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[   50.584009] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to trigger RX queues sync (-5)
[   50.584365]  intel_rapl_msr nfnetlink kvm snd_hda_core snd_hwdep irqbypass snd_pcm iwlmvm dell_laptop uvcvideo nls_iso8859_1 rapl snd_seq_midi dell_smm_hwmon intel_cstate joydev videobuf2_vmalloc snd_seq_midi_event mac80211 btusb uvc btrtl videobuf2_memops snd_rawmidi btintel videobuf2_v4l2 snd_seq libarc4 btbcm videodev input_leds videobuf2_common btmtk typec_displayport serio_raw mc snd_seq_device cmdlinepart bluetooth dell_wmi iwlwifi snd_timer spi_nor dell_smbios processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy dell_wmi_sysman processor_thermal_device dcdbas ecdh_generic ecc hid_sensor_gyro_3d hid_sensor_incl_3d hid_sensor_custom_intel_hinge hid_sensor_magn_3d hid_sensor_accel_3d hid_sensor_rotation processor_thermal_wt_hint processor_thermal_rfim firmware_attributes_class ledtrig_audio dell_wmi_descriptor wmi_bmof hid_multitouch mei_me mtd snd hid_sensor_trigger processor_thermal_rapl industrialio_triggered_buffer cfg80211 soundcore intel_rapl_common kfifo_buf processor_thermal_wt_req mei hid_sensor_iio_common industrialio
[   50.587559]  ? __iwl_err+0x18a/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[   50.588571]  intel_rapl_msr nfnetlink kvm snd_hda_core snd_hwdep irqbypass snd_pcm iwlmvm dell_laptop uvcvideo nls_iso8859_1 rapl snd_seq_midi dell_smm_hwmon intel_cstate joydev videobuf2_vmalloc snd_seq_midi_event mac80211 btusb uvc btrtl videobuf2_memops snd_rawmidi btintel videobuf2_v4l2 snd_seq libarc4 btbcm videodev input_leds videobuf2_common btmtk typec_displayport serio_raw mc snd_seq_device cmdlinepart bluetooth dell_wmi iwlwifi snd_timer spi_nor dell_smbios processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy dell_wmi_sysman processor_thermal_device dcdbas ecdh_generic ecc hid_sensor_gyro_3d hid_sensor_incl_3d hid_sensor_custom_intel_hinge hid_sensor_magn_3d hid_sensor_accel_3d hid_sensor_rotation processor_thermal_wt_hint processor_thermal_rfim firmware_attributes_class ledtrig_audio dell_wmi_descriptor wmi_bmof hid_multitouch mei_me mtd snd hid_sensor_trigger processor_thermal_rapl industrialio_triggered_buffer cfg80211 soundcore intel_rapl_common kfifo_buf processor_thermal_wt_req mei hid_sensor_iio_common industrialio
[   50.591104]  ? __iwl_err+0x18a/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[   50.592198]  intel_rapl_msr nfnetlink kvm snd_hda_core snd_hwdep irqbypass snd_pcm iwlmvm dell_laptop uvcvideo nls_iso8859_1 rapl snd_seq_midi dell_smm_hwmon intel_cstate joydev videobuf2_vmalloc snd_seq_midi_event mac80211 btusb uvc btrtl videobuf2_memops snd_rawmidi btintel videobuf2_v4l2 snd_seq libarc4 btbcm videodev input_leds videobuf2_common btmtk typec_displayport serio_raw mc snd_seq_device cmdlinepart bluetooth dell_wmi iwlwifi snd_timer spi_nor dell_smbios processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy dell_wmi_sysman processor_thermal_device dcdbas ecdh_generic ecc hid_sensor_gyro_3d hid_sensor_incl_3d hid_sensor_custom_intel_hinge hid_sensor_magn_3d hid_sensor_accel_3d hid_sensor_rotation processor_thermal_wt_hint processor_thermal_rfim firmware_attributes_class ledtrig_audio dell_wmi_descriptor wmi_bmof hid_multitouch mei_me mtd snd hid_sensor_trigger processor_thermal_rapl industrialio_triggered_buffer cfg80211 soundcore intel_rapl_common kfifo_buf processor_thermal_wt_req mei hid_sensor_iio_common industrialio
[   50.594959]  ? __iwl_err+0x18a/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[   50.596134]  intel_rapl_msr nfnetlink kvm snd_hda_core snd_hwdep irqbypass snd_pcm iwlmvm dell_laptop uvcvideo nls_iso8859_1 rapl snd_seq_midi dell_smm_hwmon intel_cstate joydev videobuf2_vmalloc snd_seq_midi_event mac80211 btusb uvc btrtl videobuf2_memops snd_rawmidi btintel videobuf2_v4l2 snd_seq libarc4 btbcm videodev input_leds videobuf2_common btmtk typec_displayport serio_raw mc snd_seq_device cmdlinepart bluetooth dell_wmi iwlwifi snd_timer spi_nor dell_smbios processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy dell_wmi_sysman processor_thermal_device dcdbas ecdh_generic ecc hid_sensor_gyro_3d hid_sensor_incl_3d hid_sensor_custom_intel_hinge hid_sensor_magn_3d hid_sensor_accel_3d hid_sensor_rotation processor_thermal_wt_hint processor_thermal_rfim firmware_attributes_class ledtrig_audio dell_wmi_descriptor wmi_bmof hid_multitouch mei_me mtd snd hid_sensor_trigger processor_thermal_rapl industrialio_triggered_buffer cfg80211 soundcore intel_rapl_common kfifo_buf processor_thermal_wt_req mei hid_sensor_iio_common industrialio
[   50.598908]  ? __iwl_err+0x18a/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[   50.600061]  intel_rapl_msr nfnetlink kvm snd_hda_core snd_hwdep irqbypass snd_pcm iwlmvm dell_laptop uvcvideo nls_iso8859_1 rapl snd_seq_midi dell_smm_hwmon intel_cstate joydev videobuf2_vmalloc snd_seq_midi_event mac80211 btusb uvc btrtl videobuf2_memops snd_rawmidi btintel videobuf2_v4l2 snd_seq libarc4 btbcm videodev input_leds videobuf2_common btmtk typec_displayport serio_raw mc snd_seq_device cmdlinepart bluetooth dell_wmi iwlwifi snd_timer spi_nor dell_smbios processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy dell_wmi_sysman processor_thermal_device dcdbas ecdh_generic ecc hid_sensor_gyro_3d hid_sensor_incl_3d hid_sensor_custom_intel_hinge hid_sensor_magn_3d hid_sensor_accel_3d hid_sensor_rotation processor_thermal_wt_hint processor_thermal_rfim firmware_attributes_class ledtrig_audio dell_wmi_descriptor wmi_bmof hid_multitouch mei_me mtd snd hid_sensor_trigger processor_thermal_rapl industrialio_triggered_buffer cfg80211 soundcore intel_rapl_common kfifo_buf processor_thermal_wt_req mei hid_sensor_iio_common industrialio
[   50.602802]  ? __iwl_err+0x18a/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[   50.603874]  intel_rapl_msr nfnetlink kvm snd_hda_core snd_hwdep irqbypass snd_pcm iwlmvm dell_laptop uvcvideo nls_iso8859_1 rapl snd_seq_midi dell_smm_hwmon intel_cstate joydev videobuf2_vmalloc snd_seq_midi_event mac80211 btusb uvc btrtl videobuf2_memops snd_rawmidi btintel videobuf2_v4l2 snd_seq libarc4 btbcm videodev input_leds videobuf2_common btmtk typec_displayport serio_raw mc snd_seq_device cmdlinepart bluetooth dell_wmi iwlwifi snd_timer spi_nor dell_smbios processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy dell_wmi_sysman processor_thermal_device dcdbas ecdh_generic ecc hid_sensor_gyro_3d hid_sensor_incl_3d hid_sensor_custom_intel_hinge hid_sensor_magn_3d hid_sensor_accel_3d hid_sensor_rotation processor_thermal_wt_hint processor_thermal_rfim firmware_attributes_class ledtrig_audio dell_wmi_descriptor wmi_bmof hid_multitouch mei_me mtd snd hid_sensor_trigger processor_thermal_rapl industrialio_triggered_buffer cfg80211 soundcore intel_rapl_common kfifo_buf processor_thermal_wt_req mei hid_sensor_iio_common industrialio
[   50.607002]  ? __iwl_err+0x18a/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[   50.608099]  intel_rapl_msr nfnetlink kvm snd_hda_core snd_hwdep irqbypass snd_pcm iwlmvm dell_laptop uvcvideo nls_iso8859_1 rapl snd_seq_midi dell_smm_hwmon intel_cstate joydev videobuf2_vmalloc snd_seq_midi_event mac80211 btusb uvc btrtl videobuf2_memops snd_rawmidi btintel videobuf2_v4l2 snd_seq libarc4 btbcm videodev input_leds videobuf2_common btmtk typec_displayport serio_raw mc snd_seq_device cmdlinepart bluetooth dell_wmi iwlwifi snd_timer spi_nor dell_smbios processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy dell_wmi_sysman processor_thermal_device dcdbas ecdh_generic ecc hid_sensor_gyro_3d hid_sensor_incl_3d hid_sensor_custom_intel_hinge hid_sensor_magn_3d hid_sensor_accel_3d hid_sensor_rotation processor_thermal_wt_hint processor_thermal_rfim firmware_attributes_class ledtrig_audio dell_wmi_descriptor wmi_bmof hid_multitouch mei_me mtd snd hid_sensor_trigger processor_thermal_rapl industrialio_triggered_buffer cfg80211 soundcore intel_rapl_common kfifo_buf processor_thermal_wt_req mei hid_sensor_iio_common industrialio
[   50.611171]  ? __iwl_err+0x18a/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[   50.611837] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwl_trans_wait_tx_queues_empty bad state = 0
[   50.623856]  intel_rapl_msr nfnetlink kvm snd_hda_core snd_hwdep irqbypass snd_pcm iwlmvm dell_laptop uvcvideo nls_iso8859_1 rapl snd_seq_midi dell_smm_hwmon intel_cstate joydev videobuf2_vmalloc snd_seq_midi_event mac80211 btusb uvc btrtl videobuf2_memops snd_rawmidi btintel videobuf2_v4l2 snd_seq libarc4 btbcm videodev input_leds videobuf2_common btmtk typec_displayport serio_raw mc snd_seq_device cmdlinepart bluetooth dell_wmi iwlwifi snd_timer spi_nor dell_smbios processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy dell_wmi_sysman processor_thermal_device dcdbas ecdh_generic ecc hid_sensor_gyro_3d hid_sensor_incl_3d hid_sensor_custom_intel_hinge hid_sensor_magn_3d hid_sensor_accel_3d hid_sensor_rotation processor_thermal_wt_hint processor_thermal_rfim firmware_attributes_class ledtrig_audio dell_wmi_descriptor wmi_bmof hid_multitouch mei_me mtd snd hid_sensor_trigger processor_thermal_rapl industrialio_triggered_buffer cfg80211 soundcore intel_rapl_common kfifo_buf processor_thermal_wt_req mei hid_sensor_iio_common industrialio


Please attach output of this terminal command: lspci -nnk -d ::0280

@RA output added

Now attach output of this terminal command: sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi. Do this after the wifi disconnect event

@RA just added the output of  sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi . Performed this after reboot, when the wifi drop was mostly seen (after logging in), but this this time it seemed that the wifi was not connected even at the logging screen

Update – while the other two laptop mentioned „recovered somehow“, my laptop get still no wifi – what is worse – no wifi now even in live session! (that is an unwanted change from previously known state).
I meanwhile tried sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware with no success.
Also tried modifiyng the iwlwifi power management with no success: sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
options iwlwifi power_save=0

@RA I changed the output of sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi as this morning the laptop wifi starts for short period of time after startup of laptop. (previous version of the output was from the "new" case when no wifi was available right after reboot). Also I noticed I omitted one info possibly important - the laptop is dual booting with Win10 (mostly not used) - the wifi is totally okay in Windows

Make sure Fast Startup is disabled in Windows

@RA it is disabled
